# Which is faster for running a sql like aggregation query Rds vs Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-rds

I am analysing user session data and I am going to calculate session length of the user. The data will be streamed from Kafka and will be stored in Either Rds or Elasticsearch. Which Db I can choose for this scenario(Rds or Elasticsearch)

Comment: Well it depends on what else you want to store, if you already have RDS ... ... ... I recommend [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as well as reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Unfortunately, most answers to this will likely be opinion-based, as opposed to fact-based, thus it doesn't make a particularly good Stack Overflow question.

Comment: For storing both the databases are good as both offering me the scalability. I am in confusion because I am going to run session aggregation query. For this which suits more for my scenario.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.